# How to call computation.stop() from within Deps.autorun()?

Tags: meteor

I am trying to stop Deps.autorun() from executing again after a condition is true:

```
Deps.autorun(function(computation){

    var first_product = Collection.products.findOne({enabled:true});

    if( first_product ){
        Session.setDefault( 'purchase_dialog.selected_product_id', first_product._id );
        console.log( 'set here');
        computation.stop();
    }

});
```

I see "set here" many time and it continues executing. Why is .stop() not working?

Comment: Is `Deps.autorun` executing inside a reactive environment already, by any chance? Say inside a template helper or a route `action`?

Comment: it's inside Template.my_template.rendered = function(){ ... }

Comment: which answers my question ;) thanks @musically_ut ! the problem is that rendered keeps executing.. So I just have to put this outside. duh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Deps.autorun` is called inside another reactive environment (say, in `Template.foo.rendered`), then it'll continue to be executed each time the parent computation is run and stopping the child computation *will not* stop the parent computation.

**Fix**: Move the call to `Deps.autorun` outside the reactive scope, to the top level.

Answer (score 1):

Call `this.stop()`

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
    if ( somethingHappens ){
        this.stop();
    }
});
```

or

```
Deps.autorun(function(computation){
    if ( somethingHappens ){
        computation.stop();
    }
});
```